# Video playback difficulties - Black screen

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, codec

I recently returned from a several month trip and found a strange problem on my home computer upon return. The computer was not used while I was away, so I'm fairly confused how this happened. I've updated the OS (Windows 7) since my return.

All video files do not show any of the video in any media player on my system. I've tried this with several different file types to make sure it wasn't simply a codec missing. Online flash videos play with no problem, but everything on my hard drive is not playing properly with the exception of iTunes files, meaning things that are in my iTunes library. I tried re-installing VLC, Media Player Classic, and the Combined Community Codec Pack, but to no avail. I'm not really sure what else to try.

Comment: Try reinstalling your graphics card drivers.